# Make Inception Feature Extraction Faster

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras

I am using the Inception Feature Extraction with my pre-trained .pb file. Extracting a features on 2GB GPU takes more time than expected. How can I make this inception feature extraction process faster. I dont want to use parallel processing or threading because I need to extract the features sequentially and want to append into some list.

```python
with tf.Session() as sess:
flattened_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('pool_3:0')

for i, image_path in enumerate(image_paths):
    if verbose:
        print('Processing %s...' % (image_path))

    if not tf.gfile.Exists(image_path):
        tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', image_path)

    image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
    feature = sess.run(flattened_tensor, {
        'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data
    })
    features[i, :] = np.squeeze(feature)
```

Comment: maybe it helps people if you tell how fast you expected it to be and how it really is?

Comment: I have 4 seconds of video of 10fps l, so it's having 40 frames and it takes nearby 4.5 seconds to extract features.So while talking about general camera we can have 25 fps that is 4 seconds of video will have 100 frames and processing 100 frames will take around 10 seconds. But I want to do it in atleast 4 seconds so it can be realtime application

Comment: i never used inception, so i don't know how long it should take. But maby compressing is an option for you. Scale the picture to on third of its original amount of pixels and you should be back in realtime.